# Date_diff problems, not working properly, PHP

Tags: php

I want to see how many days passed between two dates. Here is the code:

```
    $this->datekeencomplete = new DateTime($sqld['maxdate']);
    $this->datekcmplprint=$this->datekeencomplete->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    $this->datenow = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Almaty'));
    $this->datenowprint=$this->datenow->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
    $this->interval = date_diff($this->datekeencomplete, $this->datenow);
    $this->diff = $this->interval->format('%d');
    $this->datekeencomplete->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

This is the outcome of each variable that I get:

```
        echo"<br>$this->diff";
        echo"<br>$this->datekcmplprint";
        echo"<br>$this->datenowprint";

$this->diff: 0

$this->datekcmplprint: 03-06-2020 13:10:50

$this->datenowprint: 04-06-2020 14:32:07
```

As you may see more than 24 hours passed, but it gives 0 days, and if I try to see hours (%h) it says 21 hours. Any idea why?

I want to check if the $this->diff is more than 1 hour I allow user to go to second step.

Comment: Because of the timezone difference. As short example, the difference between `04-06-2020 11:00:00` GMT+1 and `04-06-2020 12:00:00` GMT+2 is 0. You are certainly getting a **correct result**

Comment: I'm showing both dates, what time zones do you mean? Date now is the date now with the set timezone, another date is from the database where it is stored as a value. Do I need to setup a zone for the data that is already stored as a value? If I do, then how?

Comment: You're showing formated dates **in their own local time**. This line : `new DateTime($sqld['maxdate']);` versus `new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('Asia/Almaty'));`

Comment: I see, thank you I have done as you have advised and will check. THANK YOU.